Debouncing simple plot
I add a debounce(1000) to a reactive expression
col.usr <- reactive({
    clr <- map_chr(
      seq_along(col.eog()), \(i){
        input[[str_c("cou", i)]]  
      }
    )
    names(clr) <- names(col.eog())
    clr
  })

Is there an other way to debounce a plot other than doing something like that (because my renderPlot depends on a lot of variables/inputs/reactives expressions)?
# Combine inputs into a reactive expression
combined_data <- reactive({
  list(input$num1, input$num2)
})
  
# Debounce the combined data by 1 second
debounced_data <- combined_data %>% debounce(1000)


You could use eventReactive or bindEvent to update the plot only after e.g. a certain button was pressed.
